# ActionSheet not showing properly

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet

I have this code to get NSStrings from an NSDictionary from an NSMutableArray but the problem is that it does not show right.
Here is the code:

```
UIActionSheet *playingSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hi" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
     for(NSDictionary *dict in accounts) {
         NSString *name = [dict objectForKey:@"Name"];
         [playingSheet addButtonWithTitle:name];
     }
     [playingSheet showInView:self.view];
     [playingSheet release];
```

The problem is in my case, self.view is a subview of a parentView and is loaded from an XIB and is not full screen. So the problem is my action sheet is like half the width of the iPhone's screen and it is not even touching the bottom of the screen.
In my case, how would I fix it so its the top most view (so users can see it properly), and the way a regular actionSheet is supposed to look?

Thanks!

Edit: This was the fix:

```
[playingSheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the frame of the action sheet as

```
[playingSheet setFrame:CGRectMake(0, theHeightYouWant, 320, yourDesiredHeight)];
```

"theHeightYouWant" is the height by which you must shift the action-sheet upwards/downwards to put it in the right position on the screen. You can change this by trial and error. For example, if your self.view is in the lower half of the screen, "theHeightYouWant" will be negative!

Comment: Not sure how I would set the height of the action sheet if the number of buttons change every time.

Comment: Got it fixed:
[playingSheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];

Comment: nice...I did'nt know this way! Anyway, you can make "yourDesiredHeight" vary with the number of buttons, wherein each button adds a specific amount to "yourDesiredHeight". Similarly with "theHeightYouWant".

Comment: @tipycalFlow, hi! I use showFromBarButtonItem method to show action sheet, but action sheet arrow not centered horizontally with center of bar button, how to solve this issue?

Comment: @gaussblurinc I'm sorry I couldn't visualise your problem from what you've written. Please post your query as a new question with images depicting the problem :)

Comment: @tipycalFlow, sure, ok :) see it soon here :)

Answer (score 2):

Depending how your code is set up, you could try using `self.parentViewController.view`, `self.view.window`, `self.view.superview`, or any of a variety of things. You need to provide more information if you want a more detailed answer.

Comment: None of those 3 worked. It throws this error in the console (SIGABRT): *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: view != nil'
What other things should I try?
***

Comment: I don't know because I don't know how your app is set up.